# 3D datapoints visualization

Tags: 3d, visualization

I am making measurements from accelerometer which are in format [x,y,z]. Basically the data is something lke [0.010;0.002;0.980].

I would like to draw the data thus I am looking for a tool that could do this. If you can imagine The result would be a sphere with diameter 1 centered in origin of coordinate system if I consider all the possible data (the gravity is always 1).

Which tool would allow me to import a file and draw this?

Comment: Any plotting tool or something like MATLAB or R can do this. Is there anything you've tried already, or something you got stuck with specifically?

Comment: Which function should I use? Tried plot3 but doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Best would be to show what you already have in your question, including the code you're using and the output you get (compared to what you expect), and then we'll move this over to [SO], as it's more about programming than regular software usage.